# NVIDIA driver not working since kernel update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates

I run Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version: `5.3.0-59-generic`. Recently kernel update `5.3.0-61-generic` came out, but did not get successfully installed on my system. Since then, my NVIDIA driver is not working.

If I try installing either `nvidia-driver-440` or `nvidia-driver-435` using `apt-get`, it's successful but as I try to boot into the system, an error message shows: **Failed to start Nvidia Persistence Daemon** and the login screen doesn't show up. If I go into recovery mode and purge the nvidia drivers, I can boot fine.

I also tried installing the driver using a `.run` file. In that case, I'm able to see a login screen but I'm stuck in a login loop.

I think this is a kernel installation issue, since `apt-get` fails on `5.3.0-61-generic`, and the error message shows :

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-61-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-61-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-61-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-61-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I'm already in root (I even tried `sudo su`, didn't help). So right now I'm stuck without GPU drivers on my system.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me debug this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Boot your older kernel , install nvidia driver again(whatever you had before) , then run ```sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-5.3.0-61-generic && sudo update-grub``` , and after that you should be able to use your system just as before.

Answer (score 0):

I know about this everytime you install a new Kernel.

The best approach is to uninstall every Nvidia driver and related programs.
Follow the instructions here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#removing-cuda-tk-and-driver

Then install it again.